OSM features in Overpass Turbo
I am using this overpass-turbo script to extract water polygons of the Saint Johns River in Northern Florida, but it is consistently excluding the entire portion north of the Buckman Bridge (see screenshot below). I've tried adding an estuary tag and it still excludes it... any ideas why this feature is not extracting despite the query working fine otherwise?
// Use the current map view's bounding box
(
  // Natural water features (lakes, rivers, ponds, etc.)
  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  relation["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  
  // Waterway riverbanks (wide river sections, deltas)
  way["waterway"="riverbank"]({{bbox}});
  relation["waterway"="riverbank"]({{bbox}});
  
  // Wetland areas (common in deltas and estuaries)
  way["natural"="wetland"]({{bbox}});
  relation["natural"="wetland"]({{bbox}});
  
  // Estuary-specific tagging
  way["water"="estuary"]({{bbox}});
  relation["water"="estuary"]({{bbox}});
  
  // General water-related land use (e.g., water polygons for rivers/deltas)
  way["landuse"="water"]({{bbox}});
  relation["landuse"="water"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;



You have to add coastline to your query as well, like:
[...]  
way["natural" = "coastline"]({{bbox}});
);

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Udo

But be careful - coastlines doesn't form a polygon. Depending on your needs, it might be useful to use already prepared water polygons (https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html).
